# How to access System V Shared Memory faster?

Tags: optimization, ipc, shared-memory, latency

I'm using `System V Shared Memory` to communicate between my two PHP  applications. One application is write only (*Writer*) and the other one is read only (*Reader*) on a single `Shared Memory Segment` (the data is about `900-1000 bytes`).

Both applications run using an infinite loop with a `1μs` sleep to prevent 100% CPU usage (see code sample below)

```
while(true) {
    shm_get_var($shm, 1);
    usleep(1);
}
```

It takes `~1ms` for the Reader to get the data written by the Writer from the `Shared Memory Segment`. Interestingly enough, if I remove the `usleep` from the Writer only, Reader get its data in around `500μs`. If I remove the `usleep` from the Reader only, Reader get its data in around `200μs`. The problem with removing the `usleep` is the 100% core usage.

I tried is to assign each application to the same core (using `taskset`) with both applications using `usleep` on the same core, the Reader get its data in around `300-400μs` (sometimes peaks near `900μs`). If I remove the `usleep` from the Reader and both applications are on the same core, the Reader won't get its data much faster, around `300-390μs`.

Half of a millisecond might sound ridiculous to some but speed is the most important thing in my application and makes a huge difference to me.

If someone could help me understand why I get that much of difference between my examples above that would great. Any idea about executing this faster would be tremendously appreciated.

**Specs**

- **Memory:** 12GB DDR3 (6x2GB) running at 1066 MHz
- **CPU:** Dual Intel Xeon [E5620](http://ark.intel.com/products/47925/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5620-%2812M-Cache-2_40-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI%29) @ 2.40GHz (Quad core, HyperThreading off)

---

### Updates

**#1** I tried to use [`time_nanosleep`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-nanosleep.php) to reduce the sleep time to nanoseconds instead of microseconds and Reader is still taking `~1ms`.

**#2** I have the same problem in Python as well except that it takes `~1-2ms` instead of `~1ms` like in PHP. I tried to use the `ctypes module` and `clock_nanosleep` and I'm able to get down to about `~300μs` which is not too bad but I'm looking for something even faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/results%3amore-precise-0mq-tests)

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a shot. I'll post back once I have some results. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't had the time yet to try it out but once I do and it does help, I'll approve the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If your software is limited to a single UNIX-like OS also the POSIX message queues could be used. Please find an overview here: https://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview